# Names in action bar not changing?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

A few days ago, I decided to make an Android app with a Navigation Drawer, in Eclipse (NOT Android Studio) using Material Design. It came preloaded with 3 default items in the Navigation Drawer. Since I needed more, I added some in strings.xml and added them in the array in NavigationDrawerFrament.java, and they started appearing in the Navigation Drawer.

The problem is, the names in the Action Bar didn't change. Let's assume that they came preloaded as 'thingOne', 'thingTwo' and 'thingThree', and I added 'thingFour' and 'thingFive'. If I click on thingOne, the text in the Action Bar changes to 'thingOne'. Same with thingTwo and thingThree. But if I clicked on thingFour after thingOne, then the text in the Action Bar remains as thingOne.

I need to change the text in the Action Bar. Please help soon.

**Edit:**

The code in that is executed on item select is this:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Coming soon.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Note: R.id.action_example refers to a search function I am currently working on; hence, the 'Coming soon.'

Comment: What have you read up on so far?

Comment: Everything. A lot comments in the pages, quite a bit of the documentation, even the relevant pages in the 'design' and 'develop' area of Google's [link](http://developer.android.com). Nothing seemed to answer my query. Did I miss something?

Comment: What code is executed when an item is selected in the drawer?

Comment: I'm not sure...but I think it is 'public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item).'

Comment: Ah, that code is for selections made in the overflow menu, not the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

By "Action bar name", you mean Activity name displayed in the Action Bar ? If so you might want to check out :

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Or if you're targeting API <= 10 :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you please explain with pictures exactly where the code for the item selection is and where I can add the switch-case?